# Конвертировать Word to PDF

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word

Непонятно почему при таком конвертировании PDF создается ошибкой??
Кто может обяснить в чем тут проблема?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string inputFilePath = @"Parallel Foreach.docx";
        string outPutFilePath = Path.GetDirectoryName(inputFilePath) + "\\" + "NewFileName.pdf";

        byte[] array = File.ReadAllBytes(inputFilePath);

        File.WriteAllBytes(outPutFilePath, array);
       
        Console.WriteLine("Completed...........");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Comment: Это не конвертирование. Вы всего лишь поменяли расширение файла.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov а тогда вообще можно ли из байтов ворд документа содавать пдф файл?

Comment: Из байтов - никак. docx - это зазипованный xml. Нужно распаковать его архиватором, а потом парсить xml. На основе распарсенных данных составить макет документа Word, создать аналогичный ему макет документа PDF и заполнить данными... Учитывая сложность обоих форматов (docx и pdf), за пару лет управитесь. Короче, ищите готовый конвертер.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov спасибо понятно опять дватцатьпять

Comment: Вообще есть такой изврат `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word`, суть изврата в том, чтобы програмно запустить сам Word, прочитать им файл и дать команду сохранить как PDF. Word можно запустить без окна. А изврат это, потому что это работает медленно и по причине кривизны реализации самого интеропа, придется попотеть, чтобы все заработало, но примеров в интернетах для этого добра навалом. Но вы можете поискать реально готовый конвертер в NuGet пакетах. Скорее всего этот велосипед уже изобретен во многих вариациях.

Comment: @aepot `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word` если я прав работает с `COM` не так ли?

Comment: Именно так оно и есть.

Comment: Ну, если "до начала изврата" аккуратно убивать все лишние экземпляры ворда (потому что он, собака, мог зависнуть во время предыдущих попыток) и аккуратненько дёргать его через интероп - то, наверное, изврат - это самый простой путь для C# - программы

Comment: Я когда-то пользовался уже готовыми программами для конвертации, не вордом. Платными. Бесплатные мне не понравились. Можете посмотреть в эту сторону, иногда привязка к наличию MS Office не всегда удобна в продукте.

Comment: @AK учитывая что это должно работать для юзера `IIS` вобор не так то и велик

Comment: @SH если ворд "завис", значит вы где-то незарелизили ресурсы и криво работали с COM. Доказано, проверено. Там просто действительно надо быть мастером уличной магии, чтобы подчинить себе этого интеропного зверя.

Comment: Не надо интероп. Лучше возьмите какой-нибудь пакет на nuget. Вбиваете запрос наподобие [word to pdf](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=word+to+pdf) и получаете множество библиотек.

Comment: ребята а можете подскажите какой нубуть бесплатный конвертер а то я как искал все платные. И если это вообще возможно то что бы конвертировал без проколов т.е.(какие то иконки на бакграунде или какое то информацонное строка)